# passing a file path as parameter in a angular router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Is it possible to pass a file path (e.g. `/var/logs/master.json`) in my router and use it via "req.params.path"?

I have this:

```
router.get('/file/{*path}', function (req, res)
```

Comment: No! Post the file from front-end and use fs module to read the file.

Comment: @Jai i need to harvest "/var/logs/master.json" as a parameter to a variable called `req.params.path`

Answer (score 0):

Use `router.get('/file/:p1/*/:p2/:p3)`. `*` in the endpoint would hold the path for the file.

e.g, you will get the following params object for the request`/file/value1/some/path/to/file.json/value2/value3`

`request.params = {
  "p1": "value1",
  "0": "some/path/to/file.json",
  "p2": "value2",
  "p3": "value3"
}`

Use `request.params[0]` for accessing the file path.

Comment: Thank you so much, i actually used the same thing.